# Lee Topological Manifolds Problem 4-12

Tags: general-topology, proof-writing, connectedness

I'm trying to prove the following statement:

**Problem 4-12:**
Suppose $X$ is a topological space and $S \subseteq X$ is a subset of $X$ which is both open and closed in $X$. Show that $S$ is a union of connected components of $X$.

**My attempt:** Suppose $S$ is a clopen subset, but is not a union of exclusively connected components of $X$. Instead, suppose it is the union of some collection of connected components ${U_{\alpha}}$ and some collection of generic open subsets ${V_{\alpha}}$ (to ensure that $S$ is open).

$$ S = \left( \bigcup_{\alpha} U_{\alpha} \right) \cup \left( \bigcup_{\beta} V_{\beta} \right) $$

But $S$ is also closed, so $X \setminus S$ is open. Now, $X \setminus S$ is given by
$$ X \setminus S = X - \left[ \left( \bigcup_{\alpha} U_{\alpha} \right) \cup \left( \bigcup_{\beta} V_{\beta} \right) \right] = \left(\bigcup_{\alpha} X - U_{\alpha} \right) \cup \left( \bigcup_{\beta} X - V_{\beta} \right)$$

Each of the connected components ${U_{\alpha}}$ is closed in $X$ so $ \bigcup_{\alpha} \left( X - U_{\alpha} \right)$ is open in $X$ but the ${V_{\beta}}$ are opening $X$ so $ \bigcup_{\beta} \left( X - V_{\beta} \right)$ is closed in $X$ which prevents $X \setminus S$ from being open in $X$.

I think the main idea is correct but my argument is lacking. Any suggestions/corrections/guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: It's much simpler than that. At each $s \in S$, let $C_s \subset X$ be the connected component of $X$ at $s$. Then $C_s \subseteq S$ and hence $S = \cup_{s \in S} C_s$.

Comment: Your proof can’t work - it’s obviously possible for $S$ to be a union of open sets and arbitrary connected sets since $S$ itself is open, so it’s the union of $0$ connected component and $1$ open set. Also, showing that’s not possible wouldn’t show what you want, so proof by contradiction isn’t going to help here.

Comment: Also,  clopen sets might exist, so showing something is closed doesn’t stop it from being open. Also, the complement of unions is intersection.